# How to match anything before and after a pattern in awk?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, awk

The following `awk` code searches for `$find` among the 2nd column of `file.csv` and outputs the data found in the 1st column of the first matching row:

```
awk -v pattern="$find" '$2 ~ pattern { print $1; exit }' file.csv
```

E.g., given `file.csv`:

```
1,panda
2,zebra
3,bobcat
4,lion
5,cat
```

If `$find` is set to "cat", it prints "5".

This appears to be only matching the entire contents of the cell, similar to `^cat$` in `grep`.

How can I adjust this such that it finds the first time the text appears somewhere within the cell, e.g., if `$find` is set to "cat", it prints "3", because "bobcat" contains the word "cat". In other words, rather than matching the entire cell in the CSV, if the match is found somewhere within the cell, it is sufficient.

- Only the first match should be output.

I tried the following, but they do not work as expected:

```
awk -v pattern="*$find*" '$2 ~ pattern { print $1; exit }' file.csv
```

I could find no instructions at [AWK Language Programming - Regular Expressions](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_5.html) for matching anything before and after in `awk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't. You are using a `csv` file and have not set the field separator to `,`.

Here is the output you expect:

```
$ cat file.csv
1,panda
2,zebra
3,bobcat
4,lion
5,cat
$ find=cat
$ awk -F, -v pattern="$find" '$2 ~ pattern { print $1; exit }' file.csv
3
```

For **exact** match, use `==` instead of `~`.

```
$ awk -F, -v pattern="$find" '$2==pattern { print $1; exit }' file.csv
5
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what JS explained there is another way to perform this search in **non-regex way** for the cases when your search string may contain special regex characters is by using `index` function:

```
find='cat'
awk -F, -v pattern="$find" 'index($2, pattern) { print $1; exit }' file.csv
3
```